# Log shipping with MySQL

Tags: mysql, replication

Greeting all

What is log shipping and how do we do it? I am using MySQL in a LAMPP environment.

Comment: Given hat you don't know what log shipping is, this discussion would probably be more effective if you present the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 4):

Log shipping means telling MySQL to save a separate record of every transaction, and periodically asking the slave node or nodes to read in those records.
http://www.howtoforge.com/mysql_database_replication has a decent walkthrough of how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to make a log dump for replication purposes:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-configuration.html